# How to debug a dll

Tags: windows, debugging, dll

I'm having problems with a dll that I downloaded from somewhere. How can I look inside the dll to debug it?

Answer (score 2):

You don't say, but if it's a .NET assembly dll you could use the disassembly tool in [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) to view reversed source code.

Comment: +1 good point using Reflector, I will have to try it myself as well. Is it good or awesome?

Answer (score 1):

If it doesn't have debug information then it's no use (usually DLLs are shipped in the "Release" version - which usually means that Debug information is not available). In order to **actually** debug you must also have the sources.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a program like DLL Export Viewer to view DLL files.

But as lulian pointed out you can not debug it, unless you have sources or pdb file...

Answer (score 1):

If it is a managed dll you can debug it with [.NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) Even without the symbols and without the source code. There you can

> - Decompile third-party assemblies from within VS
> - Step through decompiled assemblies and use all the debugging techniques
>     you would use on your own code